# Map and join in-view calculated value (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, view, model

I have a table where a Product can be assigned multiple rfid_tag numbers for identical products. In the main table this is done by creating a joined list of tags for each table, and going into detail elsewhere. However, I have a calculated set of ROI values I want to list in a similar manner to the rfid_tags.

```
<td>
  <%= product.rfid_tag_numbers %>
</td>   

<%product.rfid_tags.each do |tag| %>   
  <td>
    <%= number_with_precision((product.heritable_rental_price.to_f * tag.product_selections.length) / product.purchase_price.to_f, precision: 2) %> 
 </td>                                
<%end%>
```

`rfid_tag_numbers` is defined in the `Product` model as:

```
belongs_to :ancestor_product, :class_name => "Product"

def rfid_tag_numbers
    rfid_tags.map{|rfid| "##{rfid.short_number}"}.join(", ")
end
```

Simply mapping the calculation and joining as for the tag numbers does not seen to be enough. As it stands, it renders the list one cell at a time, which is not ideal - what am I missing?

Mapping attempt #1:

```
<%= rfid_tag.map{|item| number_with_precision((item.heritable_rental_price.to_f * rfid_tag.product_selections.length) / item.purchase_price.to_f, precision: 2)}.join(", ") %>
```

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: I can show the _attempt_; I tried to get it going by simply wrapping it in the map/join logic.

Comment: Should that be `rfid_tags.map` instead of `rfid_tag.map`?

Comment: Just show the entire html file and explain the problem. It's hard to understand what you are asking (which is why someone has already downvoted you).

Comment: @moveson No, it was referred to correctly from the pipes  - just changed it to `|tag|` to draw focus back to the question. Posting the whole file seems far too bulky and irrelevant. I have an `rfid_tag_numbers` method that joins `.(', ')` tag numbers in a list, and I want to make the values that come from  the `<%= number_with_precision((product.heritable_rental_price.to_f * tag.product_selections.length) / product.purchase_price.to_f, precision: 2) %>` calculation behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your model, where you've defined `rfid_tag_numbers`, you can add a new method that replicates a similar type of map:

```
def rfid_tag_numbers_with_precision
  rfid_tags.map { |rfid| number_with_precision((heritable_rental_price.to_f * rfid.product_selections.length) / purchase_price.to_f, precision: 2) }.join(", ")
end
```

You should be able to call that in your view the same way as your other method:

```
<td>
  <%= product.rfid_tag_numbers_with_precision %>
</td>
```

Comment: This works! I had to adjust when it no longer recognized `number_to_precision`, but  `rfid_tags.map { |rfid| '%.2f' % ((heritable_rental_price.to_f * rfid.product_selections.length) / purchase_price.to_f )}.join(", ")` works just as well. Thanks!